# Inserting joinpoint inside methods with AspectJ?

Tags: java, aspectj

I need to write a code coverage program for test using AspectJ plugin for Eclipse.
At the moment i know, using pointcuts, what methods are executed by JUnit test-case and how many times they are called but my problem is that I want to insert a joinpoint inside a method (for example before an 
`if-else` condition or a `for` loop) to catch the execution of a block-code with a pointcut.
According to AspectJ documentation

> Pointcuts pick out arbitrarily large numbers of join points of a
>   program. But they pick out only a small number of kinds of join
>   points. Those kinds of join points correspond to some of the most
>   important concepts in Java. Here is an incomplete list: method call,
>   method execution, exception handling, instantiation, constructor
>   execution, and field access. Each kind of join point can be picked out
>   by its own specialized pointcut that you will learn about in other
>   parts of this guide.

but I need to know when a code-branch is reached inside a method. Is there any possible solution, maybe an extension of aspectJ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: short answer is no. the aspectj language doesnt support it. you could however rewrite the class file in question (on disk, or upon loading),  to call your advice with a tool like ASM.